# Do I need to declare a drawable variable?

Tags: java, android, image, variables, loading

I'm making my first app and I'm quite happy with it, yet I need help with one thing: when setting the image for an ImageView, should I do this?

```
if (blah > 0 && blah < 10) {
    Drawable question_night = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.wt_you_should_wear_2);
    questionImg.setImageDrawable(question_night);
}
```

Or this?

```
if (blah > 0 && blah < 10){
    questionImg.setImageDrawable(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.wt_you_should_wear_2));
}
```

I need to know which is better, regarding how much VM heap it uses, whether it affects the speed of the app, if it has problems (leaks e.t.c.).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Drawable replacer = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.replacementGraphic);
linearButton.setBackgroundDrawable(replacer);
linearButton.invalidate();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will make no difference in performance or memory use. You may well find the first option easier to read and debug though.

(On the other hand, I'd name the variable somewhat differently. It's not at all clear why `question_night` would be a reference to a `Drawable`, and the conventional name would be `questionNight` anyway.)

EDIT: This answer *only* compares the two options given, from a Java language perspective. siliconeagle's answer of passing the resource directly rather than going via a `Drawable` certainly sounds like a cleaner approach to me.

Answer (score 4):

you can just use :

```
questionImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.wt_you_should_wear_2)
```

Comment: why would you need to? I think he just mean it more readable - hence debug. Obviously I think just setting the image direct is less code hence more readable.

Comment: also in the code in your comment above you dont need to call invalidate after setting the drawable. it is called internally.

Comment: no. it is not harder to debug. you'll have less object, and it is much more logic from an android point of view.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks for the help... Like aforementioned: I'm 14,no Java experience, first Android app and I've done pretty much everything from scratch until now :)